# How would you deal with a situation requiring input, wanting to see output, and also wanting to write to a file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Say I have a random executable called `prog`. This could, for example be `cat`.

Now I do the following on the CLI:

1. `./prog`
2. program now waits for input
3. I enter some input
4. The program gives me back some output.
5. I end by pressing <kbd>C-D</kbd>

At the end we have something that looks like:

```
herophant:~/working/dir$ ./prog
input
output
input2
output2
<C-D>
```

Now, I still want to see the same thing as above, but I want to write the input to some file like `test.in`, so at the end of all this, I end up with `test.in`. (And perhaps if I want, a `test.out`)

Can I do all of this without going to the hassle of writing a bash script? (Or is this the best method? I've only written them once in a while so I'm not too sure on the pros and cons, but they aren't difficult to write I think)

Comment: Make a 2-line file called `in` that contains `input` and `input2` as the 2 lines, then run `./prog < in > out` then look in file called `out`

Comment: In this case, I do not know which inputs will work, and which inputs will not work, so I have to test it out manually first. If I create an `in` file, then I could run into errors due to, for example invalid input. I basically have to do this manually first.

Comment: Ok, how about testing with `printf "input1\ninput2\n" | ./prog` Then, when you find inputs that work, hit `Up Arrow` and delete from `|` onwards and replace with `printf "input1\ninput2\n" > in` so you can run how I first suggested.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It works. But can this be made more readable somehow since I might have 10-20 lines of input or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
tee test.in | ./prog | tee test.out
```

`tee` writes stdin into a file and in stdout. So it lets the data that goes through it unchanged, and saves it into a file. See `man tee`

The first `tee` will save the input passed to the program, and the second `tee` will save the output of the program.

So at the end of the execution (exit with `Ctrl+C`), you will have a `test.in` file with the input, and an `test.out` file with the output.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider using some other outputs for text commenting the user input.

Instead of using standard `printf` function, you can use `fprintf(stderr, "Some other information");`

So this message won't be redirected using simple `>`.

I hope I understood your problem.

Comment: Just think of it as a random executable, and you don't know what language it was written in. What if the program was `cat`? C was probably an irrelevant detail.

Comment: This can not be done unless the program does not differ between two outputs. You could probably do something like this, but it does not make sense. It would make it necessary to distinguish between strings, as which is important and which not. ``` ./program | tee outputfile | grep "some_regex_rule" ```

Regular UNIX programs (as `curl`) show progress information on `stderr` and regular data on `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for here documents?

```sh
./prog <<\____HERE
input
output
input2
output2
____HERE
```

This redirects standard input to come from the next lines of the file containing the command (or from your keyboard if you copy/paste this at the prompt). You can still of course redirect standard output and standard error to files (or whatever) separately if you like.

This is pretty much identical to

```sh
printf '%s\n' input \
    output \
    input2 \
    output2 |
./prog
```